# How to create a unique schema for deep linking

Tags: flutter, unique, deep-linking

I am new to flutter development.

I want to add uni_link (https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) (deep linking) to my flutter project.

I decided to go with deep linking option since I don't have https options for my website.

According to the documentation I have to create a "unique scheme" for the link.

I assume a link like myapp://mylink.com would work and "myapp" would be this unique scheme.
And in a mobile device this would start my app.

How do I create this scheme.
Is it a configuration file that I put in the website?

Comment: You can easily integrate firebase dynamic links into your app. Also you can get https://custom.page.link domain for free.

Comment: I am still developing the app. Don't have a domain. Not sure we can create firebase dynamic links.

Comment: Dude, what I said was from my past experience. What I suggested you is what I have already implemented that's why I suggested you.

Comment: @OMiShah thank you for your suggestion. using firebase seems the best option.

Comment: remove the scheme (lisp type language) tag from your question

Comment: I have an idea how to create the flutter part. But how to create the link that the user is clicking? <a href = "myapp://mylink.com"> Click here </a>